# Printing a Select statement using SQL and REGEX_LIKE in a Test Script

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have been trying to run a Select statement . So I am not to sure what i am doing wrong. 
For example if the beginning letter is "A" and the ending letter is "D", the result should show all the customers whose name begins with A, B, C and D. If "A" and "Z" is entered the result should show all customers. I then run a FOR loop that should run through all the CNAMEs selected and then call my procedure which excepts a %TYPE of CNAME which in-turn displays in proper formating.To NOTE : my procedure works fine as i have tested it.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
UNDEFINE v_begining_letter;
UNDEFINE v_ending_letter;
DECLARE
&v_begining_letter CHAR(1);
&v_ending_letter CHAR(1);

CURSOR cur_car IS
SELECT DISTINCT(CNAME)
FROM CAR
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (CNAME, '^[&v_begining_letter-&v_ending_letter]*$' );

counter integer :=0;
BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name' || 'Total');
FOR counter IN cur_car LOOP
counter := counter+1;
cust_dep(cur_car.CNAME);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Try this `SELECT DISTINCT(CNAME)
FROM CAR
WHERE SUBSTR(CNAME, 1, 1) between v_begining_letter and v_ending_letter ;` and tell me if it solves the case. Not sure if your problem is only in that select statement. If it is, the rest of the information is irrelevant.

Comment: @g00dy Nope did not help. It just gives me an error that my counter is invalid and that my cursor is out of scope .

Comment: @g00dy Your Select Statement does not work either . the string i enters show as invalid identifiers . But my SELECT STATEMENT DOES WORK .

Comment: If it'sabout Oracle PLSQL, then this block should work: `DECLARE
v_begining_letter VARCHAR2(1);
v_ending_letter VARCHAR2(1);
CURSOR cur_car IS
  SELECT DISTINCT(CNAME) as CNAME
    FROM CAR 
   WHERE SUBSTR(CNAME, 1, 1) between v_begining_letter and v_ending_letter ;
counter number :=0;
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name' || 'Total');
  FOR c_rec IN cur_car LOOP
    counter := counter+1;
    cust_dep(c_rec.CNAME); -- That should exist as a standalone Procedure
  END LOOP;
END;
/`. I don't know what's your goal with this, but PLSQL should look like this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the Problem . The CODE is FINE .
You HAVE to NOTE that when i entered VALUES REGEX exp does not convert to uppercase (unless expressed) .
My Database Had all uppercased Alphabets (Name).